# Disabling browser's back button in laravel after logout

Tags: laravel-5

i a have developed a web application using laravel5.When i logout from the application and click the back button i still see the pages i previously visited and when i click any of the links,the application requires me to login again.How do i disable the back button of the browser so when i logout and click it i only remain at the login page.
I have tried to implement normal session destroy in my controller and here is are my codes

```
    //step 1.find the session
    session_start();

    //step 2.unset all the session variables
    $_SESSION=array();

    //step 3.Destroy the session cookies
    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])){
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
    }

    //step 4.destroy the session
    session_destroy();

    return redirect('auth);
```

Help please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you logout the user? Show us that code pls

Comment: I have created a route named logout and it is a calling a function in my controller as follows public function logout(){ Auth::logout(); return Redirect('auth'); } where auth is my route which routes the user to the login page

Comment: Please add that to your question